# React: onClick not rendering on div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

UPDATE: Turns out everything was working fine. I just had an error in my className Ternary that was causing the class not to apply. However, could someone explain why onClick does not appear on the `<div>` in the inspector?

I have a react component in which I would like to render a `<div>` with an `onClick`event. However, the `onClick`is not rendering for some reason. I have no errors in the console other than the warning: `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

The `<div>` that actually renders looks like this: `<div id="1" class="unselected">Peppered Chicken</div>`

My code looks like this. Thoughts?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div><RecipesList/></div>)
    }
}

class RecipesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            recipes: [{recipes:[]}],
            selectedRecipe: null
        };

        this.setRecipeAsSelected = this.setRecipeAsSelected.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/recipes')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(recipes => this.setState({recipes}));
    }

    setRecipeAsSelected(recipeID) {
        this.setState({selectedRecipe: recipeID})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.recipes[0]["recipes"].map((recipe, index) => {
                    return <Recipe setRecipeAsSelected={this.setRecipeAsSelected} selectedRecipe={this.state.selectedRecipe} recipe={recipe} id={index}/>
                })}
                <Generate/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Recipe extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.setThisAsSelected = this.setThisAsSelected.bind(this)
    }

    setThisAsSelected() {
        this.props.setRecipeAsSelected(this.props.id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.setThisAsSelected} key={this.props.id} id={this.props.id} className={this.props.selectedRecipe === this.props.key ? "bg-primary" : "test"}> {this.props.recipe} </div>
        )
    }
}

class Generate extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>GENERATE</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
    )
});
```

Comment: `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop` To fix this, add the key in your `RecipleList`'s render method, when mapping through to the `<Recipe />` components. ie, `<Recipe ... key={index} />`

Comment: where does `class="unselected"` come from ? It is not in the code.

Comment: I guess it should be "test". I changed it for clarity but forgot to update it on the element

Comment: Resolution in update above

Comment: @JonnyB just updated answer to include added detail as requested :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of issue can be caused by the `key` prop not being rendered on list items (ie as the warning reads). The reason `key` is important here is that React uses the unique per-item key prop to correctly resolve/determine how to update items rendered in a list (ie via `map()`) during the render cycle.

One easy way to incorporate the `key` prop is to make use of the unique "index" passed in from the map callback, as follows:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.recipes[0]["recipes"].map((recipe, index) => {
                return <Recipe 
                        setRecipeAsSelected={this.setRecipeAsSelected}
                        selectedRecipe={this.state.selectedRecipe} 
                        recipe={recipe} id={index} key={index }/> 
            })}
            <Generate/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### Update

Also, the reason you don't seeing the `onClick` attribute in the rendered HTML (ie as can be seen in dev-tools), is because the rendered HTML that dev-tools shows is not the actual JSX that you defined in your component's `render()` method(s).

The JSX that you define is actually translated to javascript behind the scenes, and as a result, the `onClick` handler gets attached to the corresponding javascript Node object for that `<div />` (this is internally done via `addEventListener()`). This therefore makes rendering the `onClick` handler into the HTML markup redundant.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. While fixing this I realized that I screwed up the ternary in setting my className. I originally was trying to pass this key={index} as a prop to give each <div> a unique key and to use in the className ternary.

Comment: However, I got an error because you can't pass key= as a prop so I just removed that prop and used id. I didn't realize why I got that error until your suggestion. The syntax for creating a prop and setting a key are they same. Trying to use key= as a prop simply set the key value on <Recipe>. After removing key= from the <Recipe> I didn't change the className ternary from this.props.key to this.props.id. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JonnyB thanks for that - glad to hear that it's working!

Comment: Any chance you know why the onClick doesn't appear in the inspector?

Comment: You use the elements tab though right? It simply isn't on the div in there.

Comment: @JonnyB oh sorry, misunderstood - yes, the reason you wont be seeing anything is because the `onClick` that youre assigning in your jsx is actually translated to javascript behind the scenes, and the onClick is attached to the js object rather than to the html markup (as I think you're expecting it to)

Comment: Can you add that to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JonnyB sure, just updated answer - hope this has helped :-)