# onSubmit, onClick, onBlur, onChange do not render in the DOM when using NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, next.js13

I am wondering if this is a possible bug? I am using NextJS 13. I'm creating a Search component using jsx. In my function I am building the form and I have an onSubmit action in the < form > element. When the page is rendered to the browser, the onSubmit is not there.

When I put in the action, method attributes, they show up. I had even put in an attribute named 'something' and it showed up in the DOM. When I changed the 'something' attribute to 'onSomething' it did not show up.

Here is my Search.jsx file.

```
'use client';

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";

function Search() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSearch = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSearch('');
        router.push(`/search/${search}`);
    }

    return (
        <div className="p-2">
            <form onSubmit={handleSearch}> <-- This is not showing up in the dev tools DOM
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="mr-2 text-black"
                    value={search}
                    placeholder="EntertheSearchTerm"
                    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
                <button type="button" className="btn bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-lg">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

This is from the DOM on the browser:

```
<div class="p-2">
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="mr-2 text-black" placeholder="EntertheSearchTerm" value="">
        <button type="button" class="btn bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-lg">Search Me</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any errors on the page or in the console. Any attribute with the 'on' in front of it is not being populated to the DOM in the dev tools.

**Question**
Is this a possible bug? Or am I missing something?

If it is a bug, I have not found any documentation for it.
I'm new to NextJS but I do not feel it is something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any attribute with the 'on' in front of it is not being populated to the DOM in the dev tools.

This is normal. React JSX props map onto HTML DOM properties, not onto HTML attributes.

Event handlers are not bound using intrinsic event attributes (which are [awful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute)).

---

Your form has an `onSubmit` event handler which will fire when the form is submitted.

Your form has a `<button type="button">` which is **not** a submit button and will **not** submit the form.

Remove the `type` attribute. (`submit` is the default type).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a bug. It may not documented in NextJS but it there in [React Documentation](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#naming-event-handler-props) because NextJS is a framework built on top of React

you can also read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#using_onevent_properties)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075832/9896311) explain the reason why react event handler is not rendered to DOM

Comment: I have read everything from the links you provided and in their case the event handler isn't showing because he is looping through data and didn't use the 'key={}'. My code isn't looping anything. It is straight rendered HTML. When I click on the submit button for the search, as you can see from the code, it is supposed to do a redirect. It never fires. Actually nothing happens :(